# How are White Walkers created in Game of Thrones?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Does anyone know how White Walkers were created and why? Or who they were created by?

Comment: Please edit your question to flesh it out.

Comment: @amflare, there's no rule about fleshing out your question? This question is there at face value that's all it needs.

Comment: This was [explained in episode 5 of season 6](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NgZFBy0zF50).

Comment: Are you watching the TV show? If so, did you miss the episode @Gallifreyan mentioned? If not, why do you want to read spoilers which may not apply to the books?

Comment: Does it matter if they want to read spoilers? Maybe they don't mind watching spoilers. Maybe they missed an episode. Any number of things are possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Children of the Forest created them to fight off the First Men

**The following answer is SHOW only**

As Gallifreyan says above this is covered in the previous Season of Game of Thrones.

To defend against the onslaught of the First Men, The Children of the Forest (The indigenous inhabitants of Westeros) created what would become known as the Night's King. How many they created or when is not known. However we know it was before the Age of Heroes, thousands of year ago.

The Children of the Forest would go on to lose control of the White Walkers and they would become the most feared enemies in Westeros and bring with them the longest Winter Westeros had ever seen. This was known as "*The Long Night*". After fighting them back with the help of Giants and The Children of the Forest and then blocked them off with The Wall, from then on manned by the Night's Watch.

Comment: Does this apply to novels as well, or only the HBO show?

Comment: AFAIK only the show